# Mapped drive is not accessible, to copy files, using Task Scheduler

Tags: batch, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, xcopy, mapped-drive

On my Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, a batch file is scheduled to run using Task Scheduler. For some reason, only a portion of the commands in the batch file are executed; Some MS DOS commands are ignored.

MS Dos Batch file looks like this:

```
s:
cd "S:\Reports\"
sqlcmd -S ipAddress -U login -P password -d dbname -i "S:\query.sql" -o "S:\Folder\Report.txt"
copy /A /Y "S:\Folder\Report.txt" Y:\
```

When I run the batch file by double-clicking on it, everything runs as intended; But when it is executed from task scheduler, only the sqlcmd portion runs correctly. The copy command does not seem to run.

The Y:\ is a mapped drive under the same login. After typing my question this far, I went back and ran one more test. Interestingly, if I replace mapped drive with local drive, everything seems to be working okay. So, at this point it looks like mapped drive is the problem. Any ideas on resolving this?

Essentially, how to copy or move files to a mapped drive (different machine) using batch file executed from Task Scheduler?

Comment: If you log what's happening by appending `>x:\dir\Batch.log 2>&1` to the first line and `>>x:\dir\Batch.log 2>&1` to each of the others, you should see what the problem is when you examine `x:\dir\Batch.log` (`x` and `dir` are a drive and directory of your choosing).

Comment: @AFH Thank you for the idea. I got a different comment that helped fix this issue. The idea was to use UNC path, rather than drive letters.

Comment: @briantist  gave the idea.

Comment: Looking at the answer, I have noticed that network drives are inaccessible to programs started through "Run as Administrator". Presumably similar restrictions apply to programs started from Task Scheduler. Worth bearing in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@briantist  (copied answer from)

`S:` and `Y:` are probably mapped network drives, but those are mapped in the context of a user session. The scheduled task will be run in its own session and won't have those drives mapped.

You should use the UNC path of the share instead (`\\server\share`) as that should work in either context (as long as the share is accessible to the user the scheduled task is running as).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge when trying to create a scheduled task on Powershell to copy files to a mapped drive. The scheduled task seemed to run but the copy operation was not working:

**Here's how I fixed it**:

First, I had to use the **UNC path** to specify the path of the mapped drive:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\MyFiles\*" -Include *.jpg -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination "\\192.168.54.20\CopiedFiles"
```

Next, I set up the scheduled job with the commands below:

```
$TaskName = "FileSync"
$Description = "This task will run periodically to sync .fin files from a specified source directory to a specified destination directory"
$ScriptPath = "C:\Users\my_userDesktop\file_sync.ps1"
$UserAccount = "COMP1\my_user"
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File $ScriptPath"
$Principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID $UserAccount -LogonType ServiceAccount
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date) -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1) -RepetitionDuration ([System.TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName -Action $Action -Description $Description -Trigger $Trigger -Principal $Principal
```

**Note**: The `$Principal` to allow the task to run whether the user is logged in or not is very essential for a scheduled job that is to sync to a mapped drive.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**